# Prove the intersection of every nonempty family of successor sets is a successor set itself

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing, peano-axioms

> Prove the intersection of every nonempty family of successor sets is a successor set itself

I thought that this would be a slightly interesting proof, since we can't really use induction to prove this (as the principle of mathematical induction comes from the Peano Axioms, which come only after we have a rigorous definition of Natural Numbers in set theory), neither can we use relations like ordering etc.

---

*My Attempted Proof*

Let $A$ be a nonempty family of successor sets. Pick $x^+ = x \cup \{x\} \in A$. 
If $x^+$ is the only element in $A$, then the proof follows trivially.

Suppose $A$ has two or more elements. Let $x^{++}$ denote the successor set of $x^{+}$, then $x^{++} = x^+ \cup \{x^+\}. $ If $A$ has two elements, $x^+$ and $x^{++}$, then we clearly have $x^+ \subset x^{++}$, and thus $\bigcap A$ is nonempty. If $A$ has more than two elements then for each set $x^{+} \in A$ having a successor set $x^{++} \in A$ we have $x^{+} \subset x^{++}$ so that $\bigcap A$ is again nonempty.

Hence the intersection of every non-empty family of successor sets is a successor set itself. $ \ \ \square$

---

Is my proof correct? If so how rigorous is it? Can it be improved in any way, also any comments on my proof writing style is greatly appreiated.

Answer (score 2):

Look up the definition of **successor set** your source uses. I do not think it means what you think it means.

Your argument seems to suppose that "successor set" means "a set that is the successor of something" -- but even so it doesn't work. You seem to get out of thin air that if your family contains two elements, then one of them will be the successor *of the other*, but you have nothing at all that tells you that.

In fact, with this meaning the goal is not true! A counterexample would be the family consisting of the two sets $\{3,\{3\}\}$ and $\{5,\{5\}\}$, which are the successors of $\{3\}$ and $\{5\}$, respectively. Its intersection is $\varnothing$, which is *not* the successor of anything.

I'm almost certain that the meaning of "successor set" that was intended for this problem was

> A set $A$ is called a **successor set** if it satisfies the following two conditions:
>
> 1. $\varnothing\in A$.
> 2. For every $x\in A$ it holds that $x^+\in A$ too.

The *Axiom of Infinity* says (in one common formulation) that at least one $A$ with this property exists. This is also known as an *inductive set*.